# What is the quickest way to evaluate an interpolated function on a polar grid in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, interpolation

I have an interpolated function of two Cartesian variables (created using `RectBivariateSpline`), and I'm looking for the fastest means of evaluating that function over a polar grid.

I've approached this problem by first defining spaces in `r` (the radial coordinate) and `t` (the angular coordinate), creating a meshgrid from these, converting this meshgrid to Cartesian coordinates, and then evaluating the function at each point by looping over the Cartesian meshgrid. The below code demonstrates this.

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline

# this shows the type of data/function I'm working with:

n = 1000
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, n)
y = np.linspace(-10, 10, n)
z = np.random.rand(n,n)

fun = RectBivariateSpline(x, y, z)

# this defines the polar grid and converts it to a Cartesian one:

nr = 1000
nt = 360

r = np.linspace(0, 10, nr)
t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, nt)

R, T = np.meshgrid(r, t, indexing = 'ij')

kx = R*np.cos(T)
ky = R*np.sin(T)

# this evaluates the interpolated function over the converted grid:

eval = np.empty((nr, nt))

for i in range(0, nr):
    for j in range(0, nt):
        eval[i][j] = fun(kx[i][j], ky[i][j])
```

In this way, I get an array whose elements match up with the `R` and `T` arrays, where `i` corresponds to `R`, and `j` to `T`. This is important, because for each radius I need to sum the evaluated function over the angular coordinate.

This approach works, but is dreadfully slow... in reality I am working with much, much larger arrays than those here. I'm looking for a way to speed this up.

One thing I've noticed is that one can submit two 1D arrays to a 2-variable function and have returned a 2D array of the function evaluated at each possible combination of the input points. Because my function isn't a polar one, however, I can't just submit my radial and angular arrays to the function. Ideally there'd be a way of converting an interpolated function to accept polar arguments, but I don't think this is possible.

I should note further that there is no way I can define the function in terms of radial coordinates in the first place: the data I'm using is output from a discrete Fourier transform, which requires rectangularly-gridded data.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By examining the `__call__` method of `RectBivariateSpline` [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.3.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.__call__.html#scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.__call__), you can use the `grid=False` option to avoid the slow double loop here.

This alone provides an order of magnitude speed up on the example you gave.  I would expect the speedup to be even better on larger data sets.

Also the answers are the same between the methods as expected.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline

# this shows the type of data/function I'm working with:

n = 1000
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, n)
y = np.linspace(-10, 10, n)
z = np.random.rand(n,n)

fun = RectBivariateSpline(x, y, z)

# this defines the polar grid and converts it to a Cartesian one:

nr = 1000
nt = 360

r = np.linspace(0, 10, nr)
t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, nt)

R, T = np.meshgrid(r, t, indexing = 'ij')

kx = R*np.cos(T)
ky = R*np.sin(T)

# this evaluates the interpolated function over the converted grid:
def evaluate_slow(kx, ky):
    eval = np.empty((nr, nt))

    for i in range(0, nr):
        for j in range(0, nt):
            eval[i][j] = fun(kx[i][j], ky[i][j])
    return eval

def evaluate_fast(kx, ky):
    eval = fun(kx.ravel(), ky.ravel(), grid=False)
    return eval  

%timeit evaluate_slow(kx, ky)
%timeit evaluate_fast(kx, ky)

eval1 = evaluate_slow(kx, ky)
eval2 = evaluate_fast(kx, ky)

print(np.all(np.isclose(eval1, eval2.reshape((nr, nt)))))

1.69 s ± 73.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
262 ms ± 2.86 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
True
```

Comment: Thank-you for your response! This approach works perfectly. I need to have the final output be in an `nr x nt` array, so I modified your evaluate_fast function to loop over the radii. I'll write up a quick answer to supplement yours.

Comment: Do you see the reshape command at the last line?  Do it that way instead.  Avoid for loops AT ALL COSTS.

Comment: Note that after reshape, I get the same answer as your original code!

Comment: Whoops - I totally missed that! Thanks for drawing my attention back to it. And, yes, with regard to avoiding for-loops, I've been recently learning as much...